# NavigationDrawer Toggle is not visible on all devices

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented my NavigationDrawer like this

```
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                                     /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,                             /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,                     /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,          /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close          /* "close drawer" description */
    );

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And for the beginning it seemed to work perfectly (Nexus 5).
Then I've tested the app on a Sony LT25i and on a Nexus S. On this devices were no icon shown...
I think it could be something with the display size, because the nexus 5 is the largest of them, but i don't know how to fix this issue.

All devices are Android 4.0 +

Comment: check logcat for messages & check that you have the right resources (ic_drawer and drawer_layout) available for those screen sizes/densities

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check the logcat and i've already checked that there are the right drawables.

Comment: The logcat is not showing some further information about that issue...

Answer (score 0):

sorry for a too late replay  use [SherlockNavigainDrawer lib](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer)

And replace the **ActionBarDrawerToggle** to  **SherlockActionBarDrawerToggle**

The  example is  given below

```
private SherlockActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
.................................
 drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 mDrawerToggle = new SherlockActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // your code
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // your code
        }
    };
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this will help you